# Which is correct? Is or Are

Tags: verbs

What is correct:  A Motion to Strike and Demurrer are now pending to the Second Amended Complaint

or

A Motion to Strike and Demurrer is now pending to the Second Amended Complaint

Comment: Is there one motion, or are there two motions?

Answer (score 2):

Take out the prepositional phrase *to Strike and Demurrer* and it is clear to see:

> A Motion **is** now pending to the Second Amended Complaint

Answer (score 1):

Well if there is only one Motion, then you would use "*is*".

> A Motion to Strike and Demurrer **is** now pending to the Second Amended Complaint.

But if there are motion(**s**) then you would use "*are*"

> Motions to Strike and Demurrer **are** now pending to the Second Amended Complaint.

So, if the subject (in this case 'motion') is plural then use **are**, but if there is only one of the subject then use **is**.

> There **are** 6 Bananas
>
> There **is** 1 Apple
>
> There **are** some cars
>
> There **is** a motorcycle.